# MySQL - Return all values if input is empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating an advanced search feature for a website and it's almost done, I'm only having one major issue.
I am matching the rooms like this:

```
AND Rooms=" .$_SESSION["room"] ."
```

and tried this as well:

```
AND (Rooms=" .$_SESSION["room"] ." OR Rooms IS NULL)
```

But the problem is if the user doesn't insert any value in the room input it won't show any room. And with the IS NULL code if I insert "8" in the rooms input if there is no matches it will display all values from the DB.
I don't want to make the input as required.

I just need a solution with mysql for when the field is empty return all values without using this:

```
if ($_SESSION["room"]==NULL) {}
else{}
```

Full query:

```
`SELECT * FROM secret WHERE secretIDName='1' AND NatureTypeIDName LIKE '%" .$_SESSION["nature"] ."%' AND (NettArea>=" 
.$_SESSION["NettArea"] ." OR NettArea IS NULL) AND ConditionTypeIDName LIKE'%" .$_SESSION["lifestyle"] 
."%' AND ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',4),'|',-1)>=" 
.$_SESSION["BusinessTypeValuesMin"] 
." AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',4),'|',-1)<=" 
.$_SESSION["BusinessTypeValuesMax"] 
.") OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',4),'|',-1) = '') AND (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',2),'|',-1)='" 
.$_SESSION["BusinessTypeValuesType"] 
."' OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',2),'|',-1)='') AND GarageArea>=" 
.$_SESSION["GarageArea"] 
." AND (LocationIDName LIKE '%" 
.$_SESSION["zone1"] 
."%' AND LocationIDName LIKE '%" 
.$_SESSION["zone2"] 
."%' AND LocationIDName LIKE '%" 
.$_SESSION["zone3"] 
."%') AND (Rooms=" 
.$_SESSION["room"] 
.") LIMIT " 
.($page-1)*$Page 
.", " .$Page ."";`
```

Comment: post your full query please

Comment: Apply check first `if(!empty('$_SESSION["room"]')){AND Rooms=" .$_SESSION["room"] ;"}`

Comment: Don't add the Rooms condition if the $_SESSION["room"] is empty.

Comment: If You don't want to create query using `if`s, You can do it like `(Rooms=".$_SESSION["room"]." OR ".$_SESSION["room"]." = ''`)

Answer (score 2):

You can create the condition like this (I assume, that the "rooms" is number representing number of rooms?):

```
AND (Rooms = ".(int)$_SESSION['room']." OR ".(int)$_SESSION['room']." = 0)
```

If `$_SESSION['room']` is empty (user haven't specified number of rooms), You get

```
AND (Rooms = 0 OR 0 = 0)
```

... which is always `TRUE`, so the "rooms" condition doesn't apply at all. If user specified number of rooms, the query would look like:

```
AND (Rooms = 8 OR 8 = 0)
```

The `8 = 0` is always `FALSE`, so effectively, You have the condition You need: `Rooms = 8`.

Comment: The data in the DB is set as null so it would try and look for 0=null which is false right?

Comment: Depends on how do You want to handle `NULL`s in database. If user specifies 8 rooms, do You want to include `NULL` records or not? You can alter the condition any way You wish, like `AND ((Rooms = '.(int)$rooms.' OR Rooms IS NULL) OR '.(int)$rooms.' = 0)` etc.

Comment: I only want to show the nulls if the input is empty, if any value is inserted i want to only show that value

Comment: I, for one, am now completely confused. So $_SESSION['room'] can be an integer or null, The attribute secret.room can be an integer or null, and if either value is null you want to see all the rows in the table? And something here is supposed to be secret?

Comment: Now i am confused, it's as simple as that, you insert the number of rooms you want, you get the exact matches. If the house as 4 rooms and you inserted 4 you will only get 4. But if i don't want to refer to the rooms I want to display all nulls and not nulls, but only if the session variable is empty

Comment: Check your comment section.

Comment: Then the answer works as-is. If user enters "nothing", then the condition is always `TRUE`, selecting all the houses regardless of `Rooms` being `NULL` or not. If user enters "x" (non-zero), then the query selects houses, that have exactly "x" rooms, excluding `NULL`s, because `(NULL = 4) OR (4 = 0)` → `(NULL) OR (FALSE)` → `FALSE`.

Comment: See simple fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iyMFUhZhnQFTc9iP9kFCPj/0

Answer (score 1):

In your query, checking NULL isn't the same as checking empty.  I'd recommend the following:

```
AND (Rooms=" .$_SESSION["room"] ." OR Rooms IS NULL OR Rooms <>'')
```

Also, it's highly recommended filtering the `$_SESSION` variable before injecting that into `MySQL`, if it's a number, assign it to `$room=(int)$_SESSION['room']` to force it to be an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the code didn't work, it displayed no data

Comment: It should have thrown an error with a null $_SESSION['room'] - that you can't see the error is a problem with your config / processes

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions, one of them is simply to store the SQL in a string variable, and then add the rooms conditions if the value is not null.

$sql = `SELECT ...`

`if ($_SESSION["room"] !== NULL) {
$sql = $sql . ' AND Rooms=".$_SESSION["room"] . " '
}`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Then you can use the `CASE WHEN` clause ... ex: `AND CASE WHEN $_SESSION["room"] <> NULL THEN Rooms=$_SESSION["room"] ELSE TRUE END` .... you just need to adapt it a bit I guess

Answer (score 0):

***Try the query like this: Note i concatenate all php varibles with {} instead of ". ."***

`SELECT * FROM secret WHERE secretIDName='1' AND NatureTypeIDName LIKE '%{$_SESSION["nature"]}%' AND (NettArea >={$_SESSION["NettArea"]} OR NettArea IS NULL) AND ConditionTypeIDName LIKE'%{$_SESSION["lifestyle"]}%' AND ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',4),'|',-1)>={$_SESSION["BusinessTypeValuesMin"]} AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',4),'|',-1)<={$_SESSION["BusinessTypeValuesMax"]}) OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',4),'|',-1) = '') AND (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',2),'|',-1)='{$_SESSION["BusinessTypeValuesType"]}' OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BusinessTypeValues,'|',2),'|',-1)='') AND GarageArea>={$_SESSION["GarageArea"]} AND (LocationIDName LIKE '%{$_SESSION["zone1"]}%' AND LocationIDName LIKE '%{$_SESSION["zone2"]}%' AND LocationIDName LIKE '%{$_SESSION["zone3"]}%') AND (Rooms={$_SESSION["room"]}) LIMIT ($page-1)*$Page, $Page";`